# Debugging with broken charging port

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm designing an android app, however the charging port on my phone was damaged and when I connect the computer to my phone, it says USB device not recognised. I have looked up debugging through bluetooth and wifi, however they either require a root, which needs me to connect my phone to the PC or they need that connection to set up the bluetooth/wifi debugging at first. I've been trying alternatively to use the emulator, however after fixing errors with the intel hardware acceleration, I now get a black screen whenever I launch the emulator. I would like to be able to debug on my phone, is there any workaround you can suggest that would work in this situation?

Comment: Isn't it possible to run ADB over WLAN ?

Comment: to run ADB you need to connect it first via USB to set it up

Comment: You don't need USB to enable root, there are exploits that run directly from the phone. Check if one is available for your phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution but it will let you grab logs from the device.
1. Enable the developer option on your phone if you have not done it already.
2. Enable "Bug report shortcut" or "Include bug reports in power menu" under developer options in settings. This will let you send an email with device logs attached to it.
3. Add whatever logs to your application and install it on the phone.
4. Run the app.
5. Send the logs in email using the option in power button menu. 
6. Go through the logs. Go to step 3 until you fix the problem.

Comment: I have a problem with installing the application I am writing in android studio on the phone first of all tho. The logs don't come until I can actually get the app onto my device. How can I transfer it onto my device without having to build it and generate an apk after every edit?

Comment: You have to transfer the APK to the device and install it. Here are a few options you can explore:
1. Use Bluetooth to transfer the APK to your device
2. Use something like DropBox. Install DropBox client both on your device and on your laptop. Transfer the apk to a dropbox directory on your laptop, sync, access it from your device, install the app.
3. Transfer the apk using SD card.

Comment: I used bluetooth, for now I am at an early stage of design so I don't need to do much debugging other than seeing how the design looks and if the animations work as expected. However, I will be getting a cheap android phone for debugging later on via USB.

Answer (score 0):

The .apk file may be easily transfered using Dropbox or any other filesharing service. Pick it up in the build outputs folder.

However this is not the best way to debug your app, one way of doing this would be to implement your own Log wrapper and to write your output to the file on an external storage.

A quick example would be:

```
public class Log {

    public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
        writeToLogFile(msg);
        return android.util.Log.v(tag, msg);
    }

    public static int d(String tag, String msg) {
        writeToLogFile(msg);
        return android.util.Log.d(tag, msg);
    }

    private static void writeToLogFile(String msg){
        // write to log file
    }

    // TODO: implement I / W / E levels logging

}
```

Also, how about using [Fabric](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary) kit for troubleshooting.